# Confusion about onSnapshot Firebase function in React. How to unsubscribed from the function and how to get only updates

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I have this code with onSnapshot function

```
useEffect(
        () =>
            onSnapshot(config(terminal!), (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                    if (change.type === 'added') {
                        console.log(change.doc.data());
                    } else if (change.type === 'removed') {
                        console.log(change.doc.data());
                    }
                });
            }),
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        [],
    );
```

My goal with these lines of code, is to listen to changes in my db in firestore, so, if someone adds something new to it, onSnapshot will let me know, and if someone deletes something, i'm expecting the same behavior.

But, when i try to look at the console.logs, it looks like,  `chane.type === 'added'` is giving me all the information that is in the db, and also the data that is added, why? Doesn't it return only the added data?

And, I have another concern about this function. I know that this works like a subscription, so, when I don't need the function, I should stop it like this

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(stuff...)

unsubscribe()
```

But, what I'm doing, is just using the useEffect without the {} so it returns the function, is that correct? I just don't know how to tell if I'm unsubscribed from Firebase.

Comment: Please check this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934260/firestore-unsubscribe-from-useeffect) if this helps your problem.

Comment: Thank you RJC, it actually helped me !

Sadly, i couldn't find that post before, so i had to make this new publication